# How to make Adobe Photoshop automatically save to Photos Library?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, photos.app, adobe-photoshop

On my MacBook Pro 2015 running macOS Monterey, I'd like to be able to set Adobe Photoshop to automatically save to my Photos.app library as the default location. I'd also like to be able to save to a device folder if desired. Is there a way to do this on Mac?

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop will save **back** to the Photos Library if you send it from there initially.

[image]

If you edit then Save in Ps, the save replaces the one in Photos, seamlessly. I've only tested this with jpg files. I don't use Photos for my 'real' work & don't have RAW, TIF or even HEIC etc in Photos to test.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Photoshop does not contemplate proper integration with photos as a default save location for all work. It does receive images from the share sheet, so if that’s good enough for your needs, you’re in luck.

Other apps do a better job of this, but you could also use a native and free tool called Folder Actions.

You would set up a folder to which photoshop saves image files (and not binary files like PSD or PSB files) to automatically import the image files to your photos library.

- http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/folder-action/index.html

If you try this by hand you will quickly decide this process will work for your needs or it will not. If you work on a couple images a week, this is fine. If you have dozens or hundreds of images a week, you will need other options.

Other excellent apps that work better with photos are in order of preference for that one item:

1. Pixelmator Pro - https://www.pixelmator.com/pro/tech-specs/
2. Acorn - https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/

All of these applications struggle once you expect layers and multiple undo steps to stay embedded in the image or other advanced features. Photos operates on a more basic “original” and “edited” state and doesn’t really allow for layers and [things that Aperture, Lightroom, Capture One, Photo Mechanic and other “pro” tools have baked in](https://learn.captureone.com/blog-posts/5-advantages-of-capture-one-pro-over-lightroom/).

Comment: Photoshop does integrate with Photos (Monterey), including PSD. Nevertheless, I agree it is not the ideal combination - I prefer Photoshop+Lightroom.

Comment: I should have mentioned the share sheet options in the first edit - thanks @Gilby for making things better. These apps are targeted at different use cases even though they all do “photo editing and organization” in different manners.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Adobe Photoshop does not have a built-in feature to automatically save files directly to the Apple Photos Library.

However, there is a workaround that you can try:

1. In the Photos app, go to **Preferences** > **General** and verify that the **Copy items to the Photos library** option is enabled.
2. In Photoshop, go to **File** > **Automate** > **Scripts** > **Image Processor**.
3. In the Image Processor window, choose the folder where your Photoshop file is saved by clicking on **Select Folder**.
4. Make sure the **Save as JPEG** option is selected, and choose a destination folder for the processed images.
5. Click on **Run** to start the image processing.
6. Once the images are processed, go to the destination folder you selected in step 4 and drag the JPEG images to the Photos app. They will be added to your Photos Library.

This method is not completely automatic, but it does provide a way to easily transfer images from Photoshop to your Photos Library.